# how to see if a string contains a substring (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, compare, substring

I want to see if a string, which is a title of a post on the apple rss news feed contains a substring, e.g. "Steve" or "Jobs". I organized the posts into a uitableview.

So there WAS a post which had Steve or Jobs in its title so I used this to check:

```
   if ([[entry title] localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:@"Steve"] == NSOrderedSame ||        [[entry title] localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: @"Jobs"] == NSOrderedSame) {

    NSLog(@"Comparism of Steve Jobs");
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"steve.png"];
}
```

But it was never called, entry is an RSSItem class which contains the title - the entry and its title is not my problem, I have checked. My comparism is the problem. How do i compare

UPDATE!

Ok here is the code:

```
NSRange range = [[[cell textLabel] text] rangeOfString:@"Steve" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"steve.png"];


}
```

I have tried it other peoples way also but SAME RESULT:

some cells have their imageView as steve.png even though their title doesnt contain steve jobs. Weird??? I scroll down and when I go back up all the dequeued cells which are reallocated and initialized have the steve jobs picture. At starting when i open the app some cells which don't have steve in their title DO HAVE THE IMAGE, and then the above happens.

My surrounding code IF NEEDED:

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"]
            autorelease];
}


tableView.autoresizingMask = 5;
tableView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
cell.autoresizingMask = 5;
cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, 20, 20);
RSSItem *item = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[[cell textLabel] setText:[item title]];
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[[cell textLabel] text]];

if (string.length > 46) {
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    UILineBreakMode lineBreak = UILineBreakModeClip;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = lineBreak;

}

[string release];

tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size: 12.0];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

NSRange range = [[[cell textLabel] text] rangeOfString:@"Steve" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"steve.png"];


    }



return cell;

    }
```

Comment: Please give the text of a few cells that falsely match "Steve".

Comment: And are you removing the image from recycled cells that are *not* "Steve"?  It doesn't look like it to me.

Comment: Text of a few cells that falsely match steve:

statement of apple board directors
100 million OSX Lion downloads in a day

Comment: then when i scroll back up all the recycled cells have the steve jobs image

Comment: "then when i scroll back up all the recycled cells have the steve jobs image" -- That's because you're not resetting the image in the recycled cells.  (Try adding `else { cell.imageView.image = nil; }` at an appropriate place.)

Comment: post this as an answer and i will vote it and tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"then when i scroll back up all the recycled cells have the steve jobs image"

That's because you're not resetting the image in the recycled cells. (Try adding

```
else { 
    cell.imageView.image = nil; 
}
```

at an appropriate place.)

Answer (score 12):

NSString-rangeOfString returns an NSRange, which can be checked for the "not found" case.

```
if ([@"Some awesome string." rangeOfString:@"awesome"].location != NSNotFound)
{
  // awesome is in 'Some awesome string.'
}
else 
{
 // awesome is not in 'Some awesome string.' 
}
```

Comment: +1 Using the `options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` version accomplishes the OP's (apparent) goal of a case-insensitive search.

Comment: for some reason this comparison gets called EVEN WHEN THAT IS NOT TRUE

Check my updated question

Answer (score 6):

You're comparing the entire string, and "Steve Jobs" won't match either "Steve" or "Jobs".  You probably want to use `rangeOfString:@"Steve" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch`, or some such.

Comment: but that won't tell me if Steve is located in the string

Comment: that returns an NSRange
nowhere close to what i want
I basically want to FIND OUT IF Steve is inside the title so I can make the image of the imageView of the cell a picture of steve jobs

Comment: It does exactly what you want. If you read the documentation, it returns an `NSRange` of `{NSNotFound, 0}` if the string is not contained.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on iOS8 you can do this now as:

```
  NSString *stringToSearch = @"Steve";
  if ([stringToSearch containsString:@"Steve"])
  {
      NSLog(@"String contains Steve!!!");
  } 
  else 
  {
      NSLog(@"String does not contain Steve!!!");
  }
```