# Objective-C String Contains String Method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, substring

How can I check if an `NSString` contains another substring, at which point it will return a `Boolean` value?

This is what I'm thinking of:

```
if myString.contains("string") then
{
    // Stuff Happens
}
```

But, from the research I've done, it seems as if Obj-C has no built-in method for this. This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28string_functions%29#Contains) gives numerous string methods, their differences, and all in different languages, but I see no Obj-C support for anything like a "contains" method.

Does anyone know of a simple-to-use method like the one above (which is similar to the C# and VB.NET function)?

Would a "find" method work? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String contains string in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/string-contains-string-in-objective-c)

Comment: Objective-C objects define methods, not functions. There is a big difference.

Comment: You can check out answer here: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/26023465/4050160>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if ([myString rangeOfString:@"string"].location != NSNotFound)
{
    // Stuff happens
}
```

Comment: iOS 8 implements `containsString:`

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *someString = @"Time for an egg hunt";

if ( [someString rangeOfString:@"egg" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound ) {
  NSLog( @"Found it!" );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be `case insensitive`.

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"string" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    return range.location;
}
else
{
    return nil;
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 2):

Create a **NSString category**, and put that in...

**Code :**

```
- (BOOL)contains:(NSString *)str
{
    NSRange aRange = [self rangeOfString:str];

    return (aRange.location!=NSNotFound);
}
```

**Usage :**

```
NSString* testStr = @"This is my string";

if ([testStr contains:@"is"])
{
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if([string rangeOfString:substring].length > 0)
    ...
```